# Undefined ExitCode

Tags: c#, exit-code

I have a simple batch file that takes the exitcode from a simple program.

In the program itself, If no exceptions occured, the main() function returns "0", otherwise it returns "1".

The batch file is being called by a monitoring system every half an hour, and takes the exitCode to decide whether the operation has been completed successfully.

From a reason I can't understand - *sometimes* the exitCode is "3"... [When I debug the program, it is always "0"... never was able to reproduce "3"]

Any suggestions?

The syntax in the batch file is as following:

start /wait "" "D:\CLEARCASE\ESB\Sources\AFM\Vip\VipTst1\bin\Debug\Vip.exe" %1 EV %2 D:\CLEARCASE\ESB\Sources\AFM\Vip\VipTst1\bin\x86\Debug
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: Refer to the program's documentation.

Comment: it is an in-house program... there's no "exitCode=3" what so ever... it might be a windows thing...

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the batch file please?

Answer (score 0):

If that is a [Windows error-code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it means:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

The program must be doing some file IO whereby the path to the file/folder is not present.

Comment: So why when we debug the program we always get "0"?

Comment: Are you running it from the same location?

Comment: Yes. We do exactly the same things over and over again. The program always return "0". Than we run the batch via the monitoring system, and sometimes we get "3", sometimes we don't. The syntaxt in the batch file is: "EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%"

Comment: Its pretty hard without the full source of the program, but a few questions would be, are there any conditions that could cause the exception from time to time (expected files not being there etc)?  Is there any way that the program could be improved to provide better diagnostics when things go wrong?

Comment: The program has a detailed log. And here things get really wierd - We decided to write the exitcode to log file, and than return and exit. We got "0" in the log file, but "3" in the monitoring system. Somethinsg happened after we exited the program